# Inverse Laplace transform through contour integration

Tags: integration, laplace-transform, inverse-problems

How can I prove that in formal way, this function doesn't have inverse Laplace transform.
$$
 F(s)=\frac{\sin(s)}{\sqrt{s}}
$$
Strictly it should be in Bromwich contour method.
Could you please tell me how to represent in poles in the contour.

Comment: But unable to found poles this function. Any help from anyone it will be great help.

Comment: curiously enough, Mathematica does return an inverse Laplace transform of $s^{-1/2}\sin s$, but a numerical check shows it's mistaken.

Comment: But I have to give a holistic approach to prove this ! But how ?

Comment: Mathematica says: $$-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi } \left(t^2+1\right)^{3/4} \sqrt{\frac{t}{\sqrt{t^2+1}}+1}}$$